# Text Mining: Cluster Analysis phrases. ERROR: cannot take a sample larger than the population

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, tm, corpus

I'm working on a dataset of thousands of sentences. The dataset is structured by a column and k rows.
I've to find some similarities between them e i'm doing a cluster Analysis. I created a corpus and converted it in numbers (TF-IDF) and then i began with the cluster analysis. When i do the kmeans, it gives me the error:"*cannot take a sample larger than the population*" and i can't continue the analysis.
I think that the problem is in the Corpus. Perhaps it should be made up of totK files and not a file with tot lines.
I have found some similar questions on the internet, but I have not found the solution.
Below is the code, thank you

```
####Stupid example of my dataset
column <- c("hi everyon, i'm Gio"," I'm Luisa, nice to meet you","How are you?", "Good morning. i'm Josh","Hello, Is Luca ok?")
df <- data.frame(column)
    corpus = tm::Corpus(tm::VectorSource(ticket_data1), readerControl = list(readerControl=readPlain))

corpus.cleaned <- tm::tm_map(corpus, tm::removeWords, tm::stopwords('english'))    #### stop-words

corpus.cleaned <- tm::tm_map(corpus, tm::stemDocument, language = "english")  

corpus.cleaned <- tm::tm_map(corpus.cleaned, tm::stripWhitespace) 

tdm <- tm::DocumentTermMatrix(corpus) 
tdm.tfidf <- tm::weightTfIdf(tdm)


tdm.tfidf <- tm::removeSparseTerms(tdm.tfidf, 0.999) 
tfidf.matrix <- as.matrix(tdm.tfidf) 

dist.matrix = proxy::dist(tfidf.matrix, method = "cosine")
k<- kmeans(tfidf.matrix, centers = 2, nstart = 25)
```

I emphasize that my dataset has about 10k lines. This is a simplified example.
I hope I was clear and that you can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me after replacing `tm::VectorSource(ticket_data1)` with `tm::VectorSource(column)`. I still get some warnings though.

Maybe a general suggestion: use `quanteda` or `tidytext` instead of `tm`. Both packages are faster, have a modern approach and are more consistent. Here is the equivalent of what you are doing in `quanteda`:

```r
column <- c("hi everyon, i'm Gio"," I'm Luisa, nice to meet you","How are you?", "Good morning. i'm Josh","Hello, Is Luca ok?")

library(quanteda)
dist.matrix <- tokens(column) %>% 
  tokens_remove(stopwords(language = "en")) %>% 
  dfm() %>% 
  dfm_trim(sparsity = 0.999) %>% 
  dfm_tfidf() %>% 
  quanteda.textstats::textstat_simil(method = "cosine")
```

`kmeans` runs perfectly in this case:

```r
set.seed(1)
kmeans(dist.matrix, centers = 2, nstart = 25)
#> K-means clustering with 2 clusters of sizes 2, 3
#> 
#> Cluster means:
#>        text1      text2    text3     text4      text5
#> 1 0.01545654 0.01545654 0.653818 0.0000000 0.65381800
#> 2 0.34416288 0.34416288 0.000000 0.3333333 0.02060872
#> 
#> Clustering vector:
#> text1 text2 text3 text4 text5 
#>     2     2     1     2     1 
#> 
#> Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
#> [1] 0.4803235 1.9587262
#>  (between_SS / total_SS =  36.2 %)
#> 
#> Available components:
#> 
#> [1] "cluster"      "centers"      "totss"        "withinss"     "tot.withinss"
#> [6] "betweenss"    "size"         "iter"         "ifault"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>